# Why did I start getting 404 errors after I changed my Wordpress permalink settings?

Tags: wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404, permalinks

After I had changed my Wordpress 4.1 Permalink-Settings, I Got 404 Errors on every page or post.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000

Options +FollowSymlinks
```

I tried to add this to my sites-available Default File:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +ExecCGI 
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/blog/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

After this I got an 500 Error.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you check your access logs?

Comment: No, I didn't.  Should I do that?

Comment: It might give you clues what is wrong

Comment: Also, was 404 custom wordpress error page or white screen with not found written?

Comment: It wasn't a custom wordpress error page.